# How to automatically return JSON response from REST controller

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I am creating a simple Rest web-service(using Spring-boot) and want to return JSON data everytime my web-service is invoked.

Here is my controller Class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
class A {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    List getAllEntitites() {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        ARepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);

        return list;
    }
}
```

The Model That I am returning is something like

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String userName;
    private String mobile;
    private String address;
}
```

When I invoke "localhost:8080/order/all" I am getting response as `[{},{}]` for 2 objects in list.

I want output something like this

```
[ {"id":100,"userName":"AA","mobile":"111111111","address":"India"} , ...]
```

I am puzzled as to what is going wrong here.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint inside getAllentities?

Comment: Java 5 came out 12 years ago, with the support for generic collections, and you're still using raw types. Why?

Comment: Did you tried to use @RestController ?

Comment: @efekctive yes I saw the return value of that method , it is correctly returning 2 User Objects

Comment: @JBNizet there are lot of small code changes I did to post this question on SO , in my code I am using Generics :)

Comment: @MosheArad I tried using `@RestController` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Vihar don't do that. Post the best, correct code, that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: If the rest paths are working then the problem is json specific.Noy sure if I can actually play with it today

Comment: However silly it might seem but the issue was caused due to an old Lombok version , updated the version and it works well now, 2 days of wasted efforts